# Computing derivatives of the sum $\sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty \frac{\lvert x \rvert}{(1 + n^2 x^2)^{3/2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, derivatives, summation, smooth-functions

Given a sum such as $\sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty \frac{\lvert x \rvert}{(1 + n^2 x^2)^\frac{3}{2}}$, the first derivative (with respect to $x$) of the summand $\frac{\lvert x \rvert}{(1 + n^2 x^2)^\frac{3}{2}}$ does not exist. Nonetheless, numerical estimates such as:
[image: numerical estimate]
seem to indicate that the sum itself is a smooth function of $x$ (and it seems like all derivatives vanish at $x=0$).

What tools are there to show that this sum defines a smooth function of $x$, and to compute the derivatives (especially at $x = 0$)?

Comment: You definitely have $f(0) = 0$, so your graph cannot be correct for small $x$.

Comment: FWIW, you can check that the limit at as $x\to 0$ of your function is equal to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dy}{(1+y^2)^{3/2}}>0$ as an application of the integral test.

Comment: @Martin R There is no mistake, there is just a discontinuity at $x=0$.

Comment: @KeeleyHoek: What I meant is this: The graph indicates that $f(0) = 2$ and all derivatives vanish at $x=0$. But that is not correct because $f(0) = 0$. And if a function is not continuous then it has no derivatives at that point.

Comment: @metamorphy That is not correct. One sees directly at least for large $\lvert x \rvert$ that only the $n=0$ term survives and the sum is asymptotically $\lvert x \rvert$ , which obviously increases. Perhaps you were fooled by errors due to numerical precision, since the graph is very flat around $x=0$.

Comment: @Martin R I see, you are obviously correct. I was sloppy in my statement of the question. I would like $x=0$ to be excluded from the domain of the sum in order to define a function, with the point $x=0$ re-added in order to make the function continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$. I suppose I should have written powers of $1/x$ in the denominator to make this clearer.

Comment: @KeeleyHoek: OK. Since two people already answered your question as written, I would suggest to post a new question with the updated problem statement (and add a reference to this one). If you change this question then the existing answers would be invalidated.

Comment: @MartinR Sure, that's understandable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit as $x\to 0$ is basically the limit of the Riemann sum for $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dt}{(1+t^2)^{3/2}}=\left.\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\right|_{-\infty}^\infty=2.$$ So the function has a discontinuity at $x=0$. On the other hand, the sum converges uniformly out of any neighborhood of $0$ (which is easy to show), hence it is continuous there (and the same argument applies for the smoothness).

Comment: Very nice! I'll keep my answer as a simple estimate, but of course this answers all questions.

Answer (score 4):

The function is not even continuous at $x=0$: We have $f(0) = 0$, but for $x = \pm \frac 1k$ with $k \in \Bbb N$ is
$$
f(x) \ge \lvert x \rvert\sum_{n = -k}^k\frac{1}{(1 + n^2 x^2)^\frac{3}{2}}
\ge \frac 1k \frac{(2k+1)}{2^{3/2}} \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \, .
$$